# Does the bone size influence its relationship with other bones?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

For example, does the size of the parent bone affect its influence over unconnected child bones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the size (scale) of the parent can influence the children size, depending on the "*inherit scale*" parameter, as shown here, in pose mode :

[image]

Comment: Ok, I get it.. so, it all depends on the 'Inherit Scale' property setting. Thank you!

Comment: However, I was referring to the actual size/length of the bone (the distance from head to tail, as set in Edit Mode) - sorry if my question was not clear enough.. Thanks for your previous answer, which I just up-voted.